# ios app life cycle when waking up from significant location change or iBeacon monitoring?

Tags: ios, core-location, lifecycle

I am following [this post on Cocoanetics](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/), but did not fully understand what happens when a killed app wakes up "in the background" (i.e. does not move to the foreground).

Obviously, `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called first. The app does not move to the foreground and therefore `applicationDidBecomeActive` should not be called (right?). What about `applicationDidEnterBackground`? Is it called?

Which functions are called when the app is suspended in the background and wakes up from significant location change?

Thanks

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case, only `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be called.